# setContentView(R.layout.activity_acknowledgement) keeps crashing my app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, error-handling, logcat

I am doing a quiz app in android studio and this setContentView(R.layout.activity_acknowledgement line from my acknowledge activity keeps crashing my project and keeps showing "the app has stopped " while running.

```
 import android.content.Intent
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.widget.Toast
 import android.view.View
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_acknowledgement.*


 class AcknowledgementActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_acknowledgement)

    btn_learn.setOnClickListener{
        if(et_name.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            val intent = Intent (this@AcknowledgementActivity, DashboardActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Logcat says that the problem is on setcontentView line.
This is my logcat

```
     at com.example.wisdomtree.AcknowledgementActivity.onCreate(AcknowledgementActivity.kt:14)
```

and this is my xml file.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".AcknowledgementActivity"
 android:background="@drawable/acknwlgemnt"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="20dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_app_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textColor="#363A43"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
    android:text="Please enter your name"
    android:textColor="#7A8089"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="540dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:textColor="#363A43"
        android:textColorHint="#7A8089"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_learn"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="620dp"
    android:background="#43A047"
    android:fontFamily="@font/chewy"
    android:text="Start Learning"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp">

</Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This line xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" from xml file and this line import android.view.View from activity keeps turning grey and I don't know what to do.

Comment: "This is my logcat" -- that is not a complete stack trace. I recommend that you edit your question and provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: Is your layout inside the 'layout' folder? Otherwise, yeah, it couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the button variable, you should probably add this line

```
btn_learn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_learn)
btn_learn.setOnClickListener{…}
```

As for the grey line, the IDE, Android studio, turns redundant variables, function, imports... to grey. Redundant cause you didn't use them in you code. If you move you cursor or click Alt-Enter on those lines, you'll see more information about it. If you have declared something like the below in you xml file,

```
<Button
   ...
   app:cornerRadius="10dp"/>
```

then this line;

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

won't turn grey.

Comment: Part of your answer is wrong. OP is using Kotlin. And, in that, you can just use the id for it